# end point connected to start point graph

Tags: python, matlab, loops, plot

I am graphing data from different MATLAB files with Python. `P0[filenumber]` and `CF[filenumber]` are arrays that have a lot of numbers from each file. I am only getting one point from each of these arrays within the files. So I made an array with just those points by appending them to a new array. When I graph my results, I get my endpoint connected to the first point, even though I broke the graph into two:

[image: Connected Grapher Picture]

How can I graph, without the last point looping to the first point? I know my data is out of order, but is there a way I can plot a nice graph without having to rearrange all of my data?

```
Max=[]
F=[]
#length is the number of files I'm reading      
for s in range(0,length):
    Max.append(P0[s][30])    
    F.append(CF[s][0])

plt.plot(F[length:],Max[length:])
plt.plot(F[0:length],Max[0:length])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is Python, not MATLAB.

Comment: You are most likely seeing this line because there is duplicate or out-of-order data in one of your arrays, placing the start point after the end point so they are connected when plotted.

Comment: I a plotting the data from MATLAB with Python....

Comment: If you want a Python answer then you should probably include the Python tag so people who use Python will actually see the question. Nothing about this question can be helped by knowing MATLAB.

Comment: See also: [mcve]